# How to dump output to a txt?

Tags: python

I want to make a simple program that extracts URLs from a site, then it dumps them to a .txt file.

The code bellow works just fine but when i try to dump it to a file i get errors.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = "https://stackoverflow.com"

page = requests.get(url)    
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
cr='C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\extracted.txt'

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
  print(link.get('href'))
```

I tried with

```
open(cr, 'w') as f:
  for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
    f.write(link.get('href'))
```

It dumps some links, not all - and they are all in one line (i get TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object)

The result in `.txt` should look like:

```
/teams/customers
/teams/use-cases
/questions
/teams
/enterprise
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising
https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f
https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent
https://stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com/help
https://chat.stackoverflow.com
https://meta.stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=site_switcher&returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent
https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=site_switcher&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f
https://stackexchange.com/sites
https://stackoverflow.blog
https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy
https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy
https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = "https://stackoverflow.com"

page = requests.get(url)    
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
cr='C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\crawler\extracted.txt'

with open(cr, 'w') as f:
 for link in soup.find_all('a'):
  print(link.get('href'))
  f.write(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: You have `f.write` but I don't see you create `f` + `write` will put them all on one line. You are responsible for formatting. Just add a `\n` after each time you call it

Comment: My bad...i added it assabled

Comment: You propably need to check if `link.get('href')` is `None` in case `href` is not defined to avoid the TypeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open(cr, 'w') as f:
   for link in soup.find_all('a'):
      link_text = link.get('href')
      if link_text is not None:
          print(link.get('href'))
          f.write(link.get('href') + '\n')
```

Comment: This is a good use case for the new walrus operator in 3.8. `if link_text := link.get('href'):`

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = "https://stackoverflow.com"

page = requests.get(url)    
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
cr= r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\extracted.txt'
links = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
    if link.get('href'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))


with open(cr, 'w') as f:
    for link in links:
        print(link)
        f.write(link + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

So... as Simon Fink suggested it works. However i found another one

```py
with open(cr, 'w') as f:
 for link in soup.find_all('a'):
  print(link.get('href'))
  try:
   f.write(link.get('href')+'\n')
  except:
      continue
```

But i think the method presented by Simon Fink is better. Much thanks

Comment: Catching every exception with just a continue might not be a good idea, it might be better if you only catch the exception that you're expecting (in this case a TypeError). So if you had other exceptions, they will be correctly raised.

Comment: I will do as you suggest. Thanks